# How to give custom configurations for the mysql my.ini file in a shared database environment

Tags: mysql

Hi, the mysql database server I'm working on hosts several other databases. I want to give a configuration like this:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=2
ft_stopword_file=""
```

for a specific database only. I don't won't to affect these changes to the other databases. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't because, its a `GLOBAL` variable look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)

So you can't even set it at at every session for that database.

```
Alternatively you can install separate instance of MySQL on the same server.
```